# How to avoid confusion with possible referenced before assignment when it won't be (Python)

Tags: python, readability

I have some code equivalent to this:

```py
state = True
if xyz:
    state = False
try:
    value = foo()
except:
    handle_exception()
    state = False
if state:
    bar(value)
```

On the last line it will appear as though `value` might be referenced before assignment, even though it won't be. This leads to code which isn't very readable. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Why not just put the call to `bar` in the `try` block?

Comment: Because (I should have included this in the question - editing it now) there are multiple things which set could state to False

Comment: Personally, I always initialize these sorts of variables to some default value like `None` or `0` or `""`, mostly out of habit from other languages where `value` would be out of scope outside the `try` block. I'm not sure if that really helps readability, though.

Comment: Does `foo()` have side effects (that you care about)? Can you just return early instead of setting `state` to `False`? Because quite often, that's the better approach to this sort of "will it or won't it run?" drama.

Comment: @ElliotWay This seems to be the most reasonable option for my scenario

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of what Phillip Kendall pointed out you should probably do something more like this:

```
state = True
if xyz:
    state = False
try:
    value = foo()
    if state:
      bar(value)
except:
    handle_exception()
```

Boolean flags are sometimes a valid option but I find that if you can find a way to avoid using them without duplicating code, you should.  They make things much harder to reason about.  For example I'm not sure what `xyz` really represents here but as written, there's no need at all for the `state` flag:

```
try:
    value = foo()
    if not xyz:
      bar(value)
except:
    handle_exception()
```

Let's say you have multiple things to check: `xyz`, `abc` and `qrs`:

```
try:
    value = foo()
    if (not xyz) and (abc) and (not qrs):
      bar(value)
except:
    handle_exception()
```

This is much easier to understand than trying to accumulate into a boolean like this:

```
if xyz:
    state = False
if not abc:
    state = False
if qrs:
    state = False

try:
    value = foo()
    if state:
      bar(value)
except:
    handle_exception()
```

If it's much more complex that just testing things, you should consider introducing methods or a class to avoid using boolean flags.  The more complexity you accumulate into this flag, the harder it will be to follow the logic.

Comment: I should have been clearer; xyz is actually a complex series of logic already, which is why I don't want to add more complexity

Comment: @retnikt It's hard to know what advice to give without seeing the actual code or something that is at least similar in structure but typically that kind of problem indicates the introduction of a method.